# How to create a target that creates a directory if it doesn't exist?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my makefile configuration, all object files get compiled into a specific directory. The compiler complains if it doesn't exist. I would like to create a makefile target that recognizes any object file and creates that directory before any other target runs and actually compiles object files.

So far, I have experimented with pattern-match and double-colon rules.

```
obj: 
    mkdir obj

obj/%.o :: | obj

obj/example.o :: src/example.cc includes/example.hh
    $(build_obj_file) # macro to do the actual job
```

With this code, only the last target runs for `obj/example.o`. I would have expected both object targets to run separately.

When I replace the pattern-match with the static `obj/example.o` I get the desired result. Also when I use static pattern-match like `obj/example.o : obj/%.o :: obj`.

I don't really want to include `obj` as an additional dependency for every other object file or to create a seperate list of all object files for static pattern matching. Either way would be very brittle and error prone.

What would you suggest to solve such a task?

Comment: FTR: Why is this tagged with `automake`?

Comment: @ndim I am sorry, this seems to be a mistake. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With (GNU) make and easy to understand rules, more or less adapted from the ruleset automake generates:

```
MKDIR_P = mkdir -p

obj/%.o: src/%.cc
    @$(MKDIR_P) $(@D)
    $(COMPILE.cc) -o $@ -c $<

obj/example.o : includes/example.hh
```

This will create the destination directory `$(@D)` for every object file `$@`, and if the destination already exists, `mkdir -p` will still exit with 0 and thus not abort the target rule set.

With (GNU) make and slightly more difficult to understand, but more efficient rules (the `obj` directory is only `mkdir -p`ed once):

```
MKDIR_P = mkdir -p

obj:
    @$(MKDIR_P) $@

obj/%.o: src/%.cc | obj
    $(COMPILE.cc) -o $@ -c $<

obj/example.o : includes/example.hh
```

The `| obj` part will make sure that the target object file will not be rebuilt just because someone has added or removed a file in `obj/` and thus changed the `obj` directory's timestamp.

The `$(COMPILE.cc)` line was basically taken from the output of GNU `make -p`.

Note that manually maintaining the header dependencies is quite error prone, so this should be autogenerated, preferably by [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist)'s [comprehensively engineered robust method](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).

Also, if your `Makefile` uses GNUmakeism, consider renaming it `GNUmakefile`.

With automake, you cannot compile with the object files being placed into a specific directory, but then the `automake` tag for this question appears to have been a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use pattern rules to "add extra prerequisites" to a set of targets.  Pattern rules *must* provide a recipe; if they don't then they are considered to [delete the pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html).

Because you have provided so little of your real makefile, it's difficult to suggest a solution that will work for you.

If you want to use order-only prerequisites you either need to add them into a pattern rule that will match your target:

```
obj/%.o : src/%.cc | obj
         $(build_obj_file)
```

or else define the prerequisite relationship separately:

```
obj/example.o: | obj
```

Comment: Actually, this is my whole makefile :D. It was only an experiment to investigate this issue (though it is working as intended after all, it seems).